# c++ template variable code efficiency

Tags: c++, templates

Consider a template function (with primitive template variable, i.e. non-class, non-struct template variable):

```
#include <iostream>

template <int m, int n>
int f() {
     return m+n;
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<2; ++j)
            std::cout << f<i,j>() << endl;
}
```

Will the compiler generate 4 copies of `f()`? or Just 1 copy, with m, n as "internal" parameters?

**UPDATE**

It seems that this code can not compile.  It seems that the template variable must be a constant. (I am not sure for this: any one?)
If so, sorry for raising a ridiculous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** your compiler was smart enough to deduce that the loops are `constexpr`, it would most likely unroll your loops and inline the function bodies.

However, when you try this with gcc, you get several errors like

```
test.cc:230:21: error: the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression
  std::cout << f < i, j > () << endl;
```

Non-constexpr template arguments are a problem, because templates need to be resolved at *compile* time, but how would a compiler resolve

```
std::cin >> a;
f< a, 2 >();
```

The compiler *cannot* make this compile-time decision and complains.

---

Apart from these obvious problems, I think your question was whether the compiler will emit several copies of the code for template instantiations with different arguments. In general, the answer is **yes**. However, modern compilers have clever ways to

- check if the template arguments are equivalent and lead to the same code
- fold binary code by identifying identical sections and deleting out all copies.

This blog from [Honza Hubička](http://hubicka.blogspot.de/2015/04/GCC5-IPA-LTO-news.html), a gcc developer, gives a nice summary of gcc5's capabilities.